# Escaping HTML to JSON with Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, escaping

I'm trying to escape HTML content from the db to JSON data. But JSON keys are escape too.
Here is an example :

> ```
> data :
> {
>   :content => "<script>alert('SOF');</script>"
> }
> ```

and in the view :

> ```
> h(@data.to_json).html_safe ->
> [{&quot;content&quot;:&quot;&lt;script&gt;alert('SOF');&lt;/script&gt;&quot;}]
> ```

Thanks for you help.

Comment: Can you be a little more descriptive of what exactly it is you're trying to do here?  You're trying to put json on an html view?  Normally someone either renders json with page of type json..

Answer (score 2):

I think your `h` is getting in the way. Try just `@data.to_json.html_safe`.

For a ton of information about putting HTML in strings in Rails (3), see [my blog entry: Presenter Pattern, Rails 3 and HTML Safe](http://rwilcox.tumblr.com/post/10546160404/presenter-pattern-rails-3-and-html-safe). (It's still useful even if you don't care about the presenter pattern).